# Cómo ajustar tamaño de imagen, cuando minimizo la pantalla

Tags: css, html5

ando empezando a utilizar razor, tengo un problema con una imagen que debiera ser responsiva, pero cuando minimizo la ventana la imagen se vuelve muy grande y no se alcanza a ver bien

```
   @{
    var saludo = FortiaWeb.Services.DynamicBar.GetSaludo();
}

<!-- START Top Navbar-->
<nav class="navbar topnavbar">
    <!-- START navbar header-->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="#/" class="navbar-brand">
            <div class="brand-logo">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <img src="~/Content/Images/anfexi/FortiaSmall.png" alt="App Logo" class="img-responsive" />
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="brand-logo-collapsed">
                <img src="~/Content/Images/anfexi/Fortia40.png" alt="App Logo" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" />
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <!-- END navbar header-->
    <!-- START Nav wrapper-->
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <!-- START Left navbar-->
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
                <!-- Button used to collapse the left sidebar. Only visible on tablet and desktops-->
                <a href="#" data-trigger-resize="" data-toggle-state="aside-collapsed" class="hidden-xs">
                    <em class="fa fa-navicon"></em>
                </a>
                <!-- Button to show/hide the sidebar on mobile. Visible on mobile only.-->
                <a href="#" data-toggle-state="aside-toggled" data-no-persist="true" class="visible-xs sidebar-toggle">
                    <em class="fa fa-navicon"></em>
                </a>
            </li>

        </ul>
        <!-- END Left navbar-->
        <!-- START Right Navbar-->
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="visible-lg">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <h4>@saludo</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>

            <!-- Fullscreen (only desktops)-->
            <li class="visible-lg">
                <a href="#" data-toggle-fullscreen="">
                    <em class="fa fa-expand"></em>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- END Right Navbar-->
    </div>
    <!-- END Nav wrapper-->


</nav>
<!-- END Top Navbar-->
```

Aquí las muestras de como se ve cuando está la pantalla maximizada
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
 y así cuando se minimiza:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me podrían dar un link o ayudarme por favor, para entender más sobre ese tema en razor, o explicar que debo hacer para que cuando se minimice la pantalla no se amontone el la imagen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes varias posibilidad, pero para mi gusto la mejor son las media query ya sea en hoja de estilos completa o simplemente en el elemento deseado

```
<!-- CSS media query on a link element -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 800px)" href="example.css" />

<!-- CSS media query within a style sheet -->
<style>
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .facet_sidebar {
    display: none;
  }
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Algo que me funciona muy bien es usar en la imagen height o width mínimo y máximo 100%

```
img {
  min-height:200px;
  min-width:200px;
  height:auto;
  width:auto;
  max-height:100%;
  max-width:100%;
}
```

De esta manera la imagen va a responder al tamaño del componente padre.

Espero te ayude.